# Documentation - Requesting additional information on a certain topic

Tags: support, documentation

It's been awhile since I've been on this site, but for the documentation stuff, how do you request for additional information/examples on a certain topic in general?

I see that you can request new topics and you can "flag" examples to request improvements to them, but I do not see any way to "flag" the entire topic to request things like additiona.

Comment: Do you mean request a new topic in a tag, or request more information for a topic that already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of each topic is a flag icon that allows you to request improvements to that topic, either for more examples, more information or for further intervention.

[image]

Selecting this puts the topic in a queue in the tag dashboard allowing other people to pick up and and make any required improvements to the topic.

[image]

Comment: Must've missed that......